# Is it possible to generate custom event on s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to enable notifications in S3 bucket, but i get JSON format long data to my registered email , i want to filter on notifications's attribute such as "object deleted" , "date-time" only, so is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to either limit the fields returned, or filter the events that get generated, you are going to have to do that yourself.

Easiest way would probably be to have the s3 event notifications sent to a custom lambda function (that you write) that can filter and/or reformat the raw s3eventnotification and then have lambda send it on to your downstream consumer, i.e. via email if you want - but there is nothing built-in to aws to do the filtering/reformatting for you.